# calling extrinsics from ink!

Tags: pallet, ink, extrinsic

How to call arbitrary pallet extrinsic from ink! ? Is there a universal approach to do that?
I'd like to engage governance's features into my ink! smart contract.

Comment: There's actually a PR in flight right now to allow this using the `call_runtime` API exposed by `pallet-contracts`: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1641.

Otherwise you have to use Chain Extensions as Justin mentioned

Answer (score 3):

I am not too sure about calling extrinsics in-specific, though I understand the main approach to calling runtime-level functions is via ink! [chain extensions](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/chain-extension/). There's also [examples of this](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/rand-extension).

Comment: your example returns a 404