# Can we call pallet function somehow from Ink smart contract?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

Can we call one of the pallet functions somehow, from [Ink smart contract](https://use.ink/)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calling extrinsics from ink!](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7158/calling-extrinsics-from-ink)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible in both way, pallet can contracts and contracts can runtime extension having pallets logic here is code for [Runtime](https://github.dev/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/psp22-extension/runtime/psp22-extension-example.rs) and contract
[Contract](https://github.dev/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/psp22-extension/runtime/psp22-extension-example.rs)